# How build.gradle file in android studio deal with relative path

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

I am using android studio 4.0.1, I have a ndk module called `app`, that has a fold structure like below image shows. Now I added a task to the highlighted `build.gradle` file, where I put:

```
task conanInstall {
    def buildDir = new File("src/main/cpp/native_lib.build")
    buildDir.mkdirs()
...
}
```

As you see, the `build.gradle` file is in the `app` folder, so I specified the path to be `src/main/cpp/native_lib.build` which is relative to the gradle file, however, this failed and I need to use `app/src/main/cpp/native_lib.build` to make it work. Why is that?

In the same gradle file I saw in the android section:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
        version "3.17.0"
    }
}
```

The path there starts with `src` rather than `app`. This confuses me on how the gradle file deals with relative path.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java.io.File` resolves relative path against the current user directory. This is what [the doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) says:

> By default the classes in the java.io package always resolve relative pathnames against the current user directory. This directory is named by the system property user.dir, and is typically the directory in which the Java virtual machine was invoked.

To resolve a path relative to current project you can use `file(...)`:

```
task conanInstall {
    def buildDir = file("src/main/cpp/native_lib.build")
    buildDir.mkdirs()
...
}
```

where `file()` is `org.gradle.api.Project#file(java.lang.Object)`, and (according to javadoc) it does exactly what you need:

```
Resolves a file path relative to the project directory of this project.
```